# Traveling to Chile with new iPhone (still sealed in box) - Will I have problems?

Tags: air-travel, cellphones, airport-security, chile, south-america

I am traveling from the USA to Santiago, Chile next week bringing a new sealed iPhone 7 for my husband. I am wondering if it's possible for me to bring it as is (in this case, unopened sealed box), or if i should take it out of the box before I travel and carry it that way. I prefer to bring it sealed, but I am worried that I am going to have issues at security. Has anyone ever had a similar experience when traveling to South America? Also, would I have to declare it in any way?

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Chilean Government FAQ for International Travelers](https://www.aduana.cl/frequently-asked-questions-international-travelers/aduana_eng/2013-04-15/142533.html), you are entitled to bring in non-commercial goods up to USD 1,500.00 FoB value.

You would then be responsible for the following duties and taxes:

1. 6% over customs or CIF value
2. 19% VAT

Now, these customs taxes and duties would be owed because you are importing a good bought overseas into Chile. You would be responsible for declaring the new phone on your customs form.

If the phone were your personal one, that you took with you, and conversely brought back with you, you would not owe these duties.